# WinRT with Syncfusion.XlsIO - Filling a SfDataGrid with content of .xls file, not showing the last row

Tags: c#, excel, syncfusion

I'm trying to fill a `SfDataGrid` with the content of a XLS file. So far I have this:

```
using (var engine = new ExcelEngine())
{
    var excel = engine.Excel;

    using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        var workbook = await excel.Workbooks.OpenAsync(stream);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        var rows = new List<object>();
        foreach (var row in worksheet.Rows)
            rows.Add(new
            {
                A = row.Cells[0].Text,
                B = row.Cells[1].Text,
                C = row.Cells[2].Text,
                D = row.Cells[3].Text,
                E = row.Cells[4].Text,
                F = row.Cells[5].Text,
                G = row.Cells[6].Text,
                H = row.Cells[7].Text,
                I = row.Cells[8].Text,
                J = row.Cells[9].Text,
            });

        var dataGrid = new SfDataGrid
        {
            ItemsSource = rows,
            ColumnSizer = GridLengthUnitType.SizeToCells
        };

        contentGrid.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
        //contentGrid.Margin = new Thickness(220, 0, 0, 150);
        contentGrid.Children.Add(dataGrid);
    }
}
```

My XLS file looks something like this:

[image]

My problem is that this piece of code fills in the first 3 `rows`, and doesn't fill in the last one. When I use a break point at `ItemsSource = rows` it shows this on the `rows` variable.

[image]

Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems i should be using

```
A = row.Cells[0].Value,
B = row.Cells[1].Value,
C = row.Cells[2].Value,
D = row.Cells[3].Value,
E = row.Cells[4].Value,
F = row.Cells[5].Value,
G = row.Cells[6].Value,
H = row.Cells[7].Value,
I = row.Cells[8].Value,
J = row.Cells[9].Value,
```

instead of `.Text`